# Inserir campo na tabela e comparar se já existe, com JQuery

Tags: jquery, array

Bom dia!
Estou inserindo produtos em uma tabela com JQuery, parecido com um carrinho de compras, e preciso comparar se o produto já não foi inserido antes.
tentei com o código abaixo, mas esta dando problemas na hora de fazer a comparação com o array,
onde estou errando?

```js
var lista = [];
var i = 0;
$('#btn-adicionar').click(function(e) {
  if (lista.length > 0) {
    var id_produto = $('#id_produto').val();
    for (j = 0; j < lista.length; j++) {
      if (jQuery.inArray(id_produto, lista[j].id_produto) == -1) {
        lista[i] = {
          id_produto: $('#id_produto').val(),
          quantidade: $('#quantidade').val(),
          preco: $('#preco').val()
        };
        $('#tabela-adicionar').append("<tr><td>" + lista[i].id_produto + "</td><td>" + lista[i].quantidade + "</td><td>" + lista[i].preco + "</td></tr>");
      } else {
        alert("Produto ja inserido");
      }
    }
    i++;
  } else {
    lista[i] = {
      id_produto: $('#id_produto').val(),
      quantidade: $('#quantidade').val(),
      preco: $('#preco').val()
    };
    $('#tabela-adicionar').append("<tr><td>" + lista[i].id_produto + "</td><td>" + lista[i].quantidade + "</td><td>" + lista[i].preco + "</td></tr>");
    i++;
  }
  $('#id_produto').val("");
  $('#quantidade').val("");
  $('#preco').val("");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-adicionar">ADD</button>
<label>Produto:</label><input type="text" id="id_produto">
<label>Qtd:</label><input type="text" id="quantidade">
<label>Preco:</label><input type="text" id="preco">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Produto</td>
      <td>Quantidade</td>
      <td>Preço</td>
      <td>Remover</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabela-adicionar">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que você está fazendo um laço `for`, não vejo muita razão em utilizar `inArray`.

Outro problema é a estrutura que criou com esse `if` dentro do `for`: da forma que está, sempre que não houver uma ocorrência, será adicionado uma entrada na array, fazendo com que seja inserido registros duplicados cada vez que o `if` for igual a `-1`.

Neste caso, seria melhor verificar pelo `for` mesmo, que inclusive deixa seu código mais simples. Não vai nem precisar desse contador `i++`. Criei uma flag `achou` que muda para `true` caso um produto já exista na array.

**Veja:**

```js
var lista = [];
$('#btn-adicionar').click(function(e) {
  if (lista.length > 0) {
    var id_produto = $('#id_produto').val();
    var achou = false;
    for(var j=0; j<lista.length; j++){
       if(lista[j].id_produto == id_produto){
          achou = true;
          break;
       }
    }
   if (!achou) {
     lista[lista.length] = {
       id_produto: $('#id_produto').val(),
       quantidade: $('#quantidade').val(),
       preco: $('#preco').val()
     };
     $('#tabela-adicionar').append("<tr><td>" + lista[lista.length-1].id_produto + "</td><td>" + lista[lista.length-1].quantidade + "</td><td>" + lista[lista.length-1].preco + "</td></tr>");
   } else {
     alert("Produto ja inserido");
   }
  } else {
    lista[0] = {
      id_produto: $('#id_produto').val(),
      quantidade: $('#quantidade').val(),
      preco: $('#preco').val()
    };
    $('#tabela-adicionar').append("<tr><td>" + lista[0].id_produto + "</td><td>" + lista[0].quantidade + "</td><td>" + lista[0].preco + "</td></tr>");
  }
  $('#id_produto').val("");
  $('#quantidade').val("");
  $('#preco').val("");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-adicionar">ADD</button>
<label>Produto:</label><input type="text" id="id_produto">
<label>Qtd:</label><input type="text" id="quantidade">
<label>Preco:</label><input type="text" id="preco">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Produto</td>
      <td>Quantidade</td>
      <td>Preço</td>
      <td>Remover</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabela-adicionar">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!